# remove nested mongo document using Casbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

Given the following data structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55760212e4b011ee8c72fb1f"),
  "firstname" : "joe",
  "lastname" : "blow",
  "email" : "jb@gmail.com",
  "sysadmin" : false,
  "siteadmin" : false,
  "sites" : [ 
    {
      "siteId" : ObjectId("55760212e4b011ee8c72fb1e"),
      "notification" : false
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to `$pull` a nested `sites` object using an `ObjectId` as search criteria. The following code:

```
val siteSearch = MongoDBObject("siteId" -> siteId)
val query = MongoDBObject("sites" -> siteSearch)
db(collection).update(query, $pull(query))
```

generates for following `query`

```
{ "sites" : { "siteId" : { "$oid" : "55760212e4b011ee8c72fb1e"}}}
```

It's not removing the site, I'm assuming because I want the `query` to look like:

```
{ "sites" : { "siteId" : ObjectId("55760212e4b011ee8c72fb1e")}}
```

I'm not sure how to make Cashbah issue the correct query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `{ "$oid" : "55760212e4b011ee8c72fb1e"}` is the JSON representation of the [BSON 12 bytes ObjectId type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/). Basically, the same thing as `ObjectId("55760212e4b011ee8c72fb1e")`. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid

Then, as you match against an array item, you need to use `$elemMatch` in your query. *But*, as `$pull` applies its query to each element as though it were a top-level object, you don't need it in the update expression.

```
val siteSearch = MongoDBObject("siteId" -> siteId)
val elemMatch = MongoDBObject("$elemMatch" -> siteSearch)

val query = MongoDBObject("sites" -> elemMatch)
val target = MongoDBOjbect("sites" -> siteSearch)

db(collection).update(query, $pull(target))
```

I don't have Casbah at hand right no, but using the [Casbah DSL](https://mongodb.github.io/casbah/guide/query_dsl.html), you might use that alternate syntax I think:

```
val query = "sites" $elemMatch siteSearch
```

---

From a Mongo shell perspective, this should be the same as:

```
query = {
    "sites" : {
        "$elemMatch" : {
            "siteId" : ObjectId("55760212e4b011ee8c72fb1e")
        }
    }
}

target = {
    "sites" : {
            "siteId" : ObjectId("55760212e4b011ee8c72fb1e")
    }
}
db.test.update(query, {$pull: target})
```

Comment: typo in the first block of code `db(collection).update(query, $pull(query))` should read `db(collection).update(query, $pull(updt))`

Comment: @andyczerwonka I've fixed that right now. Thank you for having pointed it.

Comment: @andyczerwonka I've edited my answer to show an alternate syntax using the DSL. Could you try if it works as I cannot test it right now ?